# How to use Windows user credentials for proxy authentication in R/RStudio

Tags: r, curl, rstudio, http-proxy

To install packages in RStudio on my corporate network, I need to set system `env` variables for proxy authentication:

```
Sys.setenv(https_proxy_user = "userid:password")
Sys.setenv(https_proxy = "proxy.<my.domain>:8080")
```

This works, but has the disadvantage of exposing my Windows `userid:password` in full clear text in an R script or in my `.RProfile`.

Also, if I change my Windows login, I have to adjust the script.

Is it possible to tell RStudio/R to use my Windows credentials directly for proxy authentication, [like for example this can be done in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700799/13513328)?

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Using `keyring` to store encrypted credentials doesn't seem to be an option as I would need to update these credentials manually each time I change my Windows user password.

[EDIT] As no solution was found yet, I opened an [RStudio enhancement request](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/14094)

Comment: I am still convinced `keyring` may help you. You can get those credentials with `oskeyring`. Just use `oskeyring::windows_item_enumerate()` to list them. With `oskeyring::windows_item_read` you can afterwards fetch a specific one you see on the list. Of course, you can use this, then to directly pass the value through. But you have choices: you have the choice of putting it in a protected keyring or just doing the direct pass-through of the value.

Comment: @TCamara, thanks for the hint regarding `oskeyring`. Found some apps credentials in it (Teams, SSMS, ...), but not directly my Windows User Credentials to pass to corporate proxy.

Comment: Hm. I have it listed under `target_name: MicrosoftAccount:user=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` when using `oskeyring::windows_item_enumerate()`.

Comment: @TCamara, thanks for ckecking, looks promising. I also have one `target_name: MicrosoftAccount:user=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` but it corresponds to a specific MS 365 cloud connection, not to my local Windows PC user. Were you able to extract your own local Windows PC user password this way?

Comment: @TCamara, got an answer from RStudio team : works, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening an  [RStudio enhancement request](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/14094), I got following [answer from @kevinushey](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/14094#issuecomment-1881696927) :

> It's unfortunately deprecated, but you might have better luck using
> `options(download.file.method = "wininet")` on Windows.

Turns out this still works with `R 4.3.1` and `R 4.3.2` under Windows and is exactly what I was looking for :

```
options(download.file.method = "wininet")
```

Allowed me under RStudio to use package update / install menu without specifying `https_proxy` and without exposing my Windows user credentials.

[EDIT] As `wininet` is now superseded and might disappear in coming R versions, final solution with default `curl` method is (again credit [@kevinushey](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/14094#issuecomment-1887784080)):

```
Sys.setenv(https_proxy_user = ":")
Sys.setenv(https_proxy = 'proxy.<my.domain>:proxyport')
```